# React-Select V2.0 with Next.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, emotion, server-rendering

I'm trying to use React-Select V2.0 with Next.JS but on server load the select element is not styled and flickers to styled.

I tried using the Emotion example for Next.JS to server render the emotion style (https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-emotion) but it seem to conflict with Styled-JSX which I use and I get the error `StyleSheet: insertRule accepts only strings.`

I tried using the Emotion babel config options shown here: https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/master/docs/configurable-imports.md#babel-options

but that causes the whole page to be rendered not styled and then flickers to styled.

Does anyone know how to use React-Select V2 on Next.JS with server rendering?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to the flickering render with React-Select v2.0 with Next.js is to render the component in client-side only using [react-no-ssr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-no-ssr)

Answer (score 3):

Similar to other answers here, the only way I could get this working was to use a dynamic import. I would encourage you to provide some sort of loading indicator.

```js
const ReactSelectNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('../components/select'), {
    loading: () => <Input />,
    ssr: false
});
```

If you need to test this component with Jest, [here's how](https://leerob.io/blog/things-ive-learned-building-nextjs-apps/) you would do that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I currently use Next.js [dynamic component loading without ssr](https://nextjs.org/docs/#with-no-ssr) like this:

```
const Select = dynamic(
  () => import('react-select').then((mod) => mod.default),
  {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => null,
  },
);
```

Use select component as usual